# Error message when testing an app in the Android Studio emulator: 'The app keeps stopping'

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

When I try an app I was developing in the Android Studio emulator, the following message appears: 'App keeps stopping' and it doesn't open.

This is the code for the MainActivity:

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import com.example.bookapplication.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

  class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
       setContentView(binding.root)

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

        binding.libroLeidos.setOnClickListener { Toast.makeText(this, "Entrando en Libros Leídos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            val primerIntent = Intent(this, librosLeidos::class.java)
            startActivity(primerIntent)
        }
        binding.libroPendiente.setOnClickListener { Toast.makeText(this, "Entrando en Libros Pendientes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            val segundoIntent = Intent(this, librosPendientes::class.java)
            startActivity(segundoIntent)
        }
    }}
```

On the other hand, in the LogCat, I get this message:

```
Process: com.example.bookapplication, PID: 14919
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bookapplication/com.example.bookapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ID does not reference a View inside this Activity
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ID does not reference a View inside this Activity
        at android.app.Activity.requireViewById(Activity.java:3231)
        at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.requireViewById(ActivityCompat.java:368)
        at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.java:58)
        at androidx.navigation.ActivityKt.findNavController(Activity.kt:30)
        at com.example.bookapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:24)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

The problem is that I don't know where to go to fix it. I am new to this and there are many things that are beyond me. I have found other similar questions but I have not understood well how to proceed.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You should not call setContentView twice, remove the first one. This may or may not solve your current issue though. Where is `R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main` defined?

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace from logcat points you to the call to `findNavController` (which appears to be on line 24 in your source code), where it says that it can't find the id `R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main` in your view.

Is `R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main` defined in activity_main.xml? If so, the second call to `setContentView()` is replacing that view with whatever is in `binding.root`. In that case, removing the second call could fix your issue.

If `R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main` is supposed to be defined in `binding.root`, I think you'll need to include the implementation of `com.example.bookapplication.databinding.ActivityMainBinding` in your question so we can better understand what' going on.

In any case, you shouldn't call `setContentView()` twice, as @TylerV said.